# Logstash input not working

Tags: windows, path, glob, logstash

I am trying to use the nio2path with logstash 1.4.1 (https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-2229). I am trying thix fix because I am experimencing some serious troubles when I use a glob path on windows to parse a folder of IIS logs.

This is my config:

```
input {
 nio2path {
    path=>"logs/*.log"          
   }
}
output {    
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And when I run my agent:

```
logstash-1.4.1\bin\logstash agent -f myconfig.config -l log\agent.log
```

nothing happens, the console just keep running without crashing or display some errors. The only message I get is the warning log written in my log\agent.log:

```
{:timestamp=>"2014-06-10T11:32:45.585000+0200", :message=>"Using milestone 1 input plugin 'nio2path'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks like you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/plugin-milestones", :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2014-06-10T15:13:47.846000+0200", :message=>"Interrupt received. Shutting down the pipeline.", :level=>:warn}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be useful for you.

```
 input {
 nio2path {
    path=>"logs/*.log"          
   }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
    cluster => "cluster name"
  }
 }
```